# how to upload big file by block use node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to upload a big file by using node js,but the node js using aync mode,How do I upload the big file by block.My code looks like this:

```
    var i = 0;
while(i < myObj.filesize){
    fs.readSync(in_fd, buf, 0, myObj.blockSize, null);
    i += myObj.blockSize;
    sendfile(buf); //the sendfile send data in aync mode
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to what you want is to use a readable stream and a writable one:

```
fs.createReadStream('path/to/file').pipe(destinationStream);
```